# MS ACCESS query that returns rows where one column is the same but the other isn't

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

I have a table with the following columns.

DATE - CUSTOMER - COLOR - JOBNAME -ORDERNUM

I can't figure out how to write a query to return rows that have the **same** JOBNAME but different date.

Let's say I have

```
1/9 AAA GREEN JOHN 1235
1/9 AAA GREEN JOHN 1236
1/9 AAA GREEN JOHN 1237
1/8 AAA GREEN JOHN 1238
1/9 BBB ORANGE MATT 1239
1/9 BBB ORANGE MATT 1240
1/12 CCC PINK BRETT 1241
1/5 DDD YELLOW JASON 1242
1/5 DDD YELLOW JASON 1243
```

I want the query to return only

```
1/9 AAA GREEN JOHN 1235
1/9 AAA GREEN JOHN 1236
1/9 AAA GREEN JOHN 1237
1/8 AAA GREEN JOHN 1238
```

because they have the same JOBNAME but different dates.

Comment: try researching group by functionality. it will get you what you looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would start by getting the list of jobs with different dates:

```
select jobname
from table 
group by jobname
having min(date) <> max(date);
```

If you want the complete list, then use `join` or `in` or `exists`:

```
select t.*
from table as t
where t.jobname in (select jobname
                    from table 
                    group by jobname
                    having min(date) <> max(date)
                   );
```

Comment: Nice way around count(distinct )

Answer (score 0):

Did I completely misunderstand something, or are you not just looking for:

```
SELECT *
FROM MyTable
WHERE JobName = "JOHN"
```

Because that's basically what your result set is, and it fits your request.